# MFMailComposeViewController does not send email or dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, email, ios13, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController` in a view controller with the following code:

```
if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    return
}
let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true)
```

And:

```
extension MyViewController : MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    private func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The `MFMailComposeViewController` shows as expected, but has the following behavior:

- Cancel button either does nothing (if the message has not been edited) or shows the "Delete Draft"/"Save Draft" action sheet, none of the options of which dismiss the `MFMailComposeViewController`
- The send button does nothing, whether or not it's disabled (no recipient set) or enabled (recipient set)
- The view can be dismissed by swiping it down (new iOS 13 modal behavior)

This is Xcode 11.2, iOS 13.2, Swift 4.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the delegate method is being called or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
extension MyViewController : MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    private func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Delete the keyword `private`. It hides the method from Cocoa so that it will never be called.

Comment: Yes and no. You are right to _wish_ this could be private! But it can’t be. You cannot work around this by saying `@objc private`. It’s unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your class MyViewController is not a subclass of MFMailComposeViewController.

You should:

1. Create a UIViewController subclass (class MailViewController: UIViewController)
2. Add MFMailComposeViewController.
3. MailViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Or:

Configure MFMailComposeViewController() directly from another UIViewController. For example:

```
let mailComposeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailComposeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
mailComposeVC.setToRecipients([recipient])
mailComposeVC.setSubject(subject)
mailComposeVC.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)
present(mailComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```